# Log de erros com Selenium WebDrive em C#

Tags: c#, testes, selenium-webdriver, log

Boa noite!

Estou organizando minha suíte de testes e procurando os melhores meios de criar um relatório de erros quando um teste falha. Implementei já um log em .txt com o nome do teste que é executado (utilizando o TestContext), o tempo de execução do teste, o status dele (Passou, erro, timeout...), e salvando prints caso o teste falhe.

Porém, Caso o teste falhe, também gostaria de salvar o motivo do erro, bem como o Visual Studio aponta quando debuga, ou aparece a razão da falha na própria suíte de testes. O caso é que farei um serviço rodar os testes de madrugada, e não terei acesso aos motivos escritos da falha.

Pensei em algumas possíveis soluções, só não as implementei porque acredito que haja meios melhores. Por exemplo, uma das possibilidades que imaginei fui tratar todos os testes com try/catch, e salvar o erro dentro dos catchs.

Estou usando a última versão estável do Selenium WebDriver em um projeto C#, com estrutura baseada no Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: E qual é sua dúvida? O que já fez? Onde está enfrentando problema?

Comment: 1) A melhor forma pra registrar o erro quando o teste falha. 2) Coloquei try/catchs em alguns testscases para registrar a exception. 3) Acredito que haja outro modo de capturar o erro lançado quando um teste falha, de modo que o código fique mais organizado e fácil de dar manutenção. Estou procurando esse meio

Comment: Existem diferentes maneiras de logar erros do Selenium: 1) tirar um screenshot da tela no momento do erro. 2) salvar as informações de erro do log do navegador. 3) salvar as informações de erro do próprio selenium, como mencionou.

Comment: Dherik, estou tentando fazer o que você exatamente falou no fim, salvar as informações de erro do próprio selenium, porém sem usar try/catch em todos os testcases. Os outros casos já implementei na suíte

Comment: Como o Selenium no C# pode usar o Nunit, o [NUnit Addins API](http://jimmykeen.net/2015/02/28/logging-test-results-with-nunit) deve ser o que você precisa, pois ele loga os erros do Nunit em um arquivo. É isto que procura? Se for, eu coloco como resposta.

Comment: Chegando em casa, vou conferir ele. É possível usá-lo junto com o UnitTesting da Microsoft? Senão terei que fazer uma mudança gigantesca no projeto de testes

Comment: @Dherik , usarei o seu conselho, pode colocar como resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o seu problema não seria gravar em log os erros do Selenium em si, mas em como gravar em log os erros do seus testes unitários.

Se estiver usando NUnit, uma opção para o que almeja fazer é o Nunit Addins API, no qual você consegue gravar as exceções de um teste em um arquivo separado para posterior consulta.

Dependendo da versão do NUnit, existem [outras alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691625/how-to-write-text-output-from-nunit-in-a-file#comment43798656_27691625) ainda. Se estiver usando o NUnit 3.x é [possível fazer de uma maneira](https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Text-Output-from-Tests) e com o NUnit 2.x é [possível fazer de outra](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5). Infelizmente, a documentação para estes casos me pareceu bem precária, mas vale conferir.

Comment: Retirei um link da resposta porque ele não funciona mais e estava redirecionando para um site aparentemente malicioso. Qualquer coisa, quem quiser procurar o link original ou sugerir um novo link, pode olhar no histórico de edições.